# Fetching User Identities from Zendesk ruby api wrapper

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, zendesk

I am using Zendesk API ruby wrapper https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_rb

and trying to fetch User Identities. I am trying something of this sort

```
data = client.users.identities(path: 'users/1599925012/identities').to_a
```

The issue is that I am getting a raw JSON response having Identities in response but data is still empty([])

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:-

```
ZendeskAPI::User.new(client, id: 1599925012).identities.to_a
```